# PHP ARRAY comes with "\"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, web-services

i am trying to get some Hashtags from the data base and sending to the ios app via json encoding.

but unfortunately i am getting some "\" in the array

```
    {
    "error_code": 0,
    "response_string": "success.",
    "result":    "#manchesterunited\",\"#manunited\",\"#mufc\",\"#manchesterisred\",\"#manunitedisred\",\"#middleast"
}
```

but i need the values as below

```
{
    "error_code": 0,
    "response_string": "success.",
    "result": {
        "#manchesterunited",
        "#manunited",
        "#mufc",
        "#manchesterisred",
        "#manunitedisred",
        "#middleast"
    }
}
```

my php code

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$params = json_decode($jsonInput,true);

$searchword = isset($params['hash'])?$params['hash']:'';


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `hashtags` FROM `video`");

//Fetching the sql data

$hashtags = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $hashtags[] =  $row['hashtags'];  
}

$hashtags = array_unique($hashtags);
$string = rtrim(implode($hashtags));


$string = explode(",", $string);
$string = array_unique($string);

// Search the array with "preg_match" function.
$matches = array();
foreach($string as $k=>$v) {
   if(preg_match("/^$searchword/", $v)) {
    unset($matches[$k]);
        $matches[$k] = $v;
   }
}

$output = array_slice($matches, 0, 10, true);
$value = implode(",", $output);


echo json_encode(array("error_code"=>0,'response_string'=>'success.','result' =>$output));
exit;
```

This is the PHP code i am using for get the data from db and fetch.

Comment: Can you `echo` the result of $sql, so that we can find out where the error lies.

Comment: Does the data in the database have quotes?

Comment: @bIgBoY `Array
(
    [0] => #fifa,#manchesterunited,#manunited,#talent,#mufc,#manchesterisred,#manunitedisred,
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => #dubai,#emirates,#uae,#middleast,
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => #Doha,#Timelaps,
    [7] => 
    [8] => #blossom,#ultramotion,
    [9] => �#qatar,#qatarairways,#airbus350xwb,
    [10] => 
    [11] => #qatar,
) `

Comment: Does `$output = stripslashes($output);` help?

Comment: `str_replace('\', '',$output);` might also work.

Comment: @lockdown66 the output you shared has multiple hashtags in one index. Are you sure that is the output you receive? Also come to think of it, why don't you use `LIKE` in sql instead of using `preg_match` to avoid a whole lotta processing?

Comment: Looks as though `addslashes();` has been used somewhere along the line .

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace();` or `stripslashes();` with stripslashes it would be:

```
$output = stripslashes(array_slice($matches, 0, 10, true));
$value = implode(",", $output);
```

or in two stages

```
$output = array_slice($matches, 0, 10, true);
$output = stripslashes($output);
$value = implode(",", $output);
```

or with `str_replace()`

```
$output = array_slice($matches, 0, 10, true);
$output = str_replace('\', '', $output);
$value = implode(",", $output);
```